# Let $x_i \in \mathbb Z,$ such that $|x_1|+|x_2|+|x_3|+...+|x_{10}|=100.$ Find number of solution.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Let $x_i \in \mathbb Z,$ such that $|x_1|+|x_2|+|x_3|+...+|x_{10}|=100.$ Find number of solution.

I found this problem in Book named Pathfinder for Olympiad mathematics.

I tried using making cases but there are many cases.

Then i see the answer key but i don't know how did the obtained the following result.
$$\sum_{r=0}^{9}2^{10-r}\cdot {10\choose r}\cdot{99\choose 9-r}$$

**Also is there any other method to solve given problem?**

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Stars and Bars is the natural place to start.

Comment: Try to solve the related question where the $x_i$ are necessarily elements of $\Bbb N$.  Recognize that a positive number and a negative number give the same absolute value... so for each non-zero number pick if it was positive or if it was negative.  That's what the $2^n$ term was about, but $+0$ and $-0$ are the same thing to us, so we needed to break into cases based on number of zeroes.  That's what the $\sum$ was about.  We needed to pick which terms were the ones that were zero, that's what the $\binom{10}{r}$ was about.  The last piece is explained by stars-and-bars.

Comment: Without the absolute values, this is called the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $100$. The absolute value adds the fact that each (non-zero) number used in the partition can be positive or negative, you'll need to multiply the result by $2^{\text{# of non-zero values used}}$.

Comment: @DanielP no, partitions are specifically written in decreasing order of summands (*or depending on author in increasing order*).  Here we have no such restriction on the $x_i$.  This would be in the link a *composition*, not a partition... but not just *any* composition.  No, we are talking specifically about *restricted* compositions into $10$ parts where we allow zeroes.  After that many clarifications and corrections, it becomes more confusing than helpful to have brought partitions or compositions up in the first place.  Call it a stars-and-bars problem and be done with it.

Comment: Hint: count the number of solutions where exactly $r$ of the ten variables are zero, then sum over $r$.

Comment: @JMoravitz do you want to post your comment as an answer?